# Fourier Transform of X,Y data(Python)

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm currently trying to Fourier transform a laser spectrum.
The original data was in text file form and I imported the data using numpy.

As the data is for a laser spectrum, the X value is the wavelength of the laser and the Y value stands for the intensity of the laser.

Using the code below, I plotted the laser spectrum as such

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import genfromtxt
from matplotlib import pyplot

filelist = []
time = [0.00,-1.33,-2.67,-4.00,-5.33,-6.67]
offset = 0

index = 0

filelist.append("0.SSM")

for i in range (1,6):
    filelist.append("-%s00.SSM" %i)

for fname in filelist:
    data = np.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter='  ',unpack=True,skip_header=2)
    X=data[0,:]
    Y=data[1,:]
    offset = offset + 500
    plt.plot(X,Y+offset,label=str(time[index])+'ps')
    index=index+1
    plt.xlim([759,850])
    axes=plt.gca

pyplot.title("Laser Spectrum of Both Pumps with Negative Time Delay(Pump 1 = 796nm, Pump 2 = 804nm)")
plt.xlabel("Wavelength[nm]")
plt.ylabel("Counts[arb.unit]")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.savefig('796and804nmminus')
plt.show()
```

This is how my laser spectrum looks like.
[image]

The problem here is when I try to Fourier transform this graph.
I Fourier-transformed the Y value and manually converted the X-value(wavelength) to time. (By using the wavelength-frequency relation for electromagnetic wave)

I think the way I'm handling the X value is wrong as it does not start at 0s. Is there a way to Fourier transform the Y value in terms of the X value when they are kept in an array?

The code that I used for Fourier transform is as below.
As this was a trial run, only used one text file for the data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import genfromtxt
from matplotlib import pyplot

filelist = []
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft,rfft

sol = 299792458.00 #this is the speed of light in m/s


time = [0.00]

offset = 0

index = 0

filelist.append("0.SSM")

# for i in range (1,6):
#     filelist.append("-%s00.SSM" %i)

for fname in filelist:
    data = np.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter='  ',unpack=True,skip_header=2)
    X=data[0,:]
    F=sol/X
    Y=data[1,:]
    Z1=rfft(Y)

    time1 = (1/F)*10**6

    plt.plot(time1,Z1,label=str(time[index])+'ps')
    index=index+1
    plt.xlim([2.2,2.5])
    axes=plt.gca

pyplot.title("Laser Spectrum of Both Pumps with Negative Time Delay(Pump 1 = 796nm, Pump 2 = 804nm)")
plt.xlabel("Time[ms]")
plt.ylabel("Counts[arb.unit]")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.savefig('796and804nmminus')
plt.show()
```

And this is how my "Fourier-transformed"(at least I think the FT worked) graph looks like.

[image]

Both my mathematical knowledge and programming knowledge are a bit shaky, so any help/advice is much appreciated.

Btw, this is how my data file looks like

```
" File: Sabrina\20171212\796and804\0.SSM
" SCOPE->  Wave:814.54nm  Pix:1050  Val:225.600  Time:5ms  Avg:5  Sm:1  Sg:0  Tc:off  Z Y  Xt:1  Ch:1 
 688.00  2.113E+002
 688.25  2.093E+002
 688.50  2.116E+002
 688.75  2.166E+002
 689.00  2.125E+002
 689.25  2.130E+002
 689.50  2.096E+002
 689.75  2.139E+002
 690.00  2.138E+002
 690.25  2.128E+002
 690.50  2.117E+002
 690.75  2.087E+002
 691.00  2.079E+002
 691.25  2.098E+002
 691.50  2.114E+002
 691.75  2.114E+002
 692.00  2.116E+002
 692.25  2.135E+002
 692.50  2.150E+002
 692.75  2.146E+002
 693.00  2.131E+002
 693.25  2.125E+002
 693.50  2.115E+002
 693.75  2.110E+002
 694.00  2.126E+002
 694.25  2.135E+002
 694.50  2.135E+002
 694.75  2.141E+002
 695.00  2.154E+002
 695.25  2.171E+002
 695.50  2.176E+002
 695.75  2.183E+002
 696.00  2.181E+002
 696.25  2.154E+002
 696.50  2.141E+002
 696.75  2.141E+002
 697.00  2.160E+002
 697.25  2.165E+002
 697.50  2.168E+002
 697.75  2.165E+002
 698.00  2.164E+002
 698.25  2.153E+002
 698.50  2.155E+002
 698.75  2.146E+002
 699.00  2.115E+002
 699.25  2.107E+002
 699.50  2.124E+002
 699.75  2.148E+002
 700.00  2.164E+002
 700.25  2.172E+002
 700.50  2.182E+002
 700.75  2.195E+002
 701.00  2.196E+002
 701.25  2.200E+002
 701.50  2.213E+002
 701.75  2.218E+002
 702.00  2.217E+002
 702.25  2.222E+002
 702.50  2.203E+002
 702.75  2.173E+002
 703.00  2.153E+002
 703.25  2.166E+002
 703.50  2.184E+002
 703.75  2.195E+002
 704.00  2.191E+002
 704.25  2.187E+002
 704.50  2.178E+002
 704.75  2.184E+002
 705.00  2.196E+002
 705.25  2.206E+002
 705.50  2.200E+002
 705.75  2.203E+002
 706.00  2.198E+002
 706.25  2.206E+002
 706.50  2.203E+002
 706.75  2.210E+002
 707.00  2.203E+002
 707.25  2.190E+002
 707.50  2.191E+002
 707.75  2.204E+002
 708.00  2.206E+002
 708.25  2.204E+002
 708.50  2.211E+002
 708.75  2.206E+002
 709.00  2.208E+002
 709.25  2.201E+002
 709.50  2.194E+002
 709.75  2.181E+002
 710.00  2.179E+002
 710.25  2.205E+002
 710.50  2.235E+002
 710.75  2.242E+002
 711.00  2.247E+002
 711.25  2.257E+002
 711.50  2.268E+002
 711.75  2.271E+002
 712.00  2.266E+002
 712.25  2.247E+002
 712.50  2.232E+002
 712.75  2.223E+002
 713.00  2.247E+002
 713.25  2.252E+002
 713.50  2.222E+002
 713.75  2.219E+002
 714.00  2.241E+002
 714.25  2.250E+002
 714.50  2.223E+002
 714.75  2.224E+002
 715.00  2.223E+002
 715.25  2.217E+002
 715.50  2.212E+002
 715.75  2.210E+002
 716.00  2.221E+002
 716.25  2.246E+002
 716.50  2.260E+002
 716.75  2.253E+002
 717.00  2.251E+002
 717.25  2.239E+002
 717.50  2.220E+002
 717.75  2.210E+002
 718.00  2.212E+002
 718.25  2.230E+002
 718.50  2.254E+002
 718.75  2.282E+002
 719.00  2.317E+002
 719.25  2.333E+002
 719.50  2.312E+002
 719.75  2.303E+002
 720.00  2.305E+002
 720.25  2.297E+002
 720.50  2.282E+002
 720.75  2.261E+002
 721.00  2.232E+002
 721.25  2.235E+002
 721.50  2.240E+002
 721.75  2.248E+002
 722.00  2.266E+002
 722.25  2.288E+002
 722.50  2.306E+002
 722.75  2.313E+002
 723.00  2.308E+002
 723.25  2.294E+002
 723.50  2.281E+002
 723.75  2.278E+002
 724.00  2.281E+002
 724.25  2.280E+002
 724.50  2.274E+002
 724.75  2.266E+002
 725.00  2.260E+002
 725.25  2.254E+002
 725.50  2.262E+002
 725.75  2.263E+002
 726.00  2.273E+002
 726.25  2.283E+002
 726.50  2.283E+002
 726.75  2.299E+002
 727.00  2.307E+002
 727.25  2.314E+002
 727.50  2.312E+002
 727.75  2.322E+002
 728.00  2.308E+002
 728.25  2.298E+002
 728.50  2.284E+002
 728.75  2.283E+002
 729.00  2.277E+002
 729.25  2.270E+002
 729.50  2.291E+002
 729.75  2.316E+002
 730.00  2.308E+002
 730.25  2.308E+002
 730.50  2.300E+002
 730.75  2.286E+002
 731.00  2.264E+002
 731.25  2.267E+002
 731.50  2.281E+002
 731.75  2.297E+002
 732.00  2.307E+002
 732.25  2.302E+002
 732.50  2.294E+002
 732.75  2.293E+002
 733.00  2.299E+002
 733.25  2.304E+002
 733.50  2.300E+002
 733.75  2.279E+002
 734.00  2.279E+002
 734.25  2.297E+002
 734.50  2.314E+002
 734.75  2.322E+002
 735.00  2.320E+002
 735.25  2.317E+002
 735.50  2.300E+002
 735.75  2.271E+002
 736.00  2.263E+002
 736.25  2.268E+002
 736.50  2.284E+002
 736.75  2.302E+002
 737.00  2.317E+002
 737.25  2.321E+002
 737.50  2.324E+002
 737.75  2.326E+002
 738.00  2.328E+002
 738.25  2.311E+002
 738.50  2.287E+002
 738.75  2.259E+002
 739.00  2.244E+002
 739.25  2.245E+002
 739.50  2.248E+002
 739.75  2.255E+002
 740.00  2.273E+002
 740.25  2.299E+002
 740.50  2.315E+002
 740.75  2.313E+002
 741.00  2.285E+002
 741.25  2.248E+002
 741.50  2.230E+002
 741.75  2.245E+002
 742.00  2.262E+002
 742.25  2.280E+002
 742.50  2.293E+002
 742.75  2.292E+002
 743.00  2.282E+002
 743.25  2.301E+002
 743.50  2.320E+002
 743.75  2.341E+002
 744.00  2.335E+002
 744.25  2.323E+002
 744.50  2.307E+002
 744.75  2.302E+002
 745.00  2.291E+002
 745.25  2.284E+002
 745.50  2.286E+002
 745.75  2.288E+002
 746.00  2.296E+002
 746.25  2.293E+002
 746.50  2.307E+002
 746.75  2.345E+002
 747.00  2.374E+002
 747.25  2.382E+002
 747.50  2.371E+002
 747.75  2.359E+002
 748.00  2.341E+002
 748.25  2.325E+002
 748.50  2.301E+002
 748.75  2.271E+002
 749.00  2.260E+002
 749.25  2.273E+002
 749.50  2.294E+002
 749.75  2.312E+002
 750.00  2.323E+002
 750.25  2.326E+002
 750.50  2.323E+002
 750.75  2.326E+002
 751.00  2.336E+002
 751.25  2.324E+002
 751.50  2.326E+002
 751.75  2.326E+002
 752.00  2.326E+002
 752.25  2.307E+002
 752.50  2.291E+002
 752.75  2.298E+002
 753.00  2.297E+002
 753.25  2.298E+002
 753.50  2.315E+002
 753.75  2.327E+002
 754.00  2.314E+002
 754.25  2.297E+002
 754.50  2.302E+002
 754.75  2.326E+002
 755.00  2.337E+002
 755.25  2.323E+002
 755.50  2.299E+002
 755.75  2.266E+002
 756.00  2.270E+002
 756.25  2.312E+002
 756.50  2.337E+002
 756.75  2.339E+002
 757.00  2.332E+002
 757.25  2.341E+002
 757.50  2.340E+002
 757.75  2.324E+002
 758.00  2.332E+002
 758.25  2.326E+002
 758.50  2.312E+002
 758.75  2.304E+002
 759.00  2.287E+002
 759.25  2.262E+002
 759.50  2.261E+002
 759.75  2.281E+002
 760.00  2.293E+002
 760.25  2.289E+002
 760.50  2.278E+002
 760.75  2.285E+002
 761.00  2.299E+002
 761.25  2.310E+002
 761.50  2.304E+002
 761.75  2.295E+002
 762.00  2.299E+002
 762.25  2.306E+002
 762.50  2.296E+002
 762.75  2.282E+002
 763.00  2.268E+002
 763.25  2.267E+002
 763.50  2.266E+002
 763.75  2.259E+002
 764.00  2.246E+002
 764.25  2.251E+002
 764.50  2.259E+002
 764.75  2.286E+002
 765.00  2.295E+002
 765.25  2.292E+002
 765.50  2.291E+002
 765.75  2.300E+002
 766.00  2.296E+002
 766.25  2.283E+002
 766.50  2.272E+002
 766.75  2.276E+002
 767.00  2.291E+002
 767.25  2.290E+002
 767.50  2.309E+002
 767.75  2.337E+002
 768.00  2.344E+002
 768.25  2.336E+002
 768.50  2.329E+002
 768.75  2.301E+002
 769.00  2.280E+002
 769.25  2.264E+002
 769.50  2.272E+002
 769.75  2.284E+002
 770.00  2.295E+002
 770.25  2.300E+002
 770.50  2.309E+002
 770.75  2.314E+002
 771.00  2.307E+002
 771.25  2.297E+002
 771.50  2.295E+002
 771.75  2.297E+002
 772.00  2.315E+002
 772.25  2.321E+002
 772.50  2.296E+002
 772.75  2.271E+002
 773.00  2.264E+002
 773.25  2.269E+002
 773.50  2.280E+002
 773.75  2.298E+002
 774.00  2.299E+002
 774.25  2.290E+002
 774.50  2.294E+002
 774.75  2.301E+002
 775.00  2.307E+002
 775.25  2.304E+002
 775.50  2.298E+002
 775.75  2.303E+002
 776.00  2.314E+002
 776.25  2.327E+002
 776.50  2.328E+002
 776.75  2.330E+002
 777.00  2.342E+002
 777.25  2.336E+002
 777.50  2.322E+002
 777.75  2.296E+002
 778.00  2.267E+002
 778.25  2.259E+002
 778.50  2.269E+002
 778.75  2.288E+002
 779.00  2.294E+002
 779.25  2.300E+002
 779.50  2.301E+002
 779.75  2.295E+002
 780.00  2.281E+002
 780.25  2.276E+002
 780.50  2.268E+002
 780.75  2.258E+002
 781.00  2.261E+002
 781.25  2.263E+002
 781.50  2.285E+002
 781.75  2.304E+002
 782.00  2.316E+002
 782.25  2.318E+002
 782.50  2.329E+002
 782.75  2.316E+002
 783.00  2.312E+002
 783.25  2.311E+002
 783.50  2.310E+002
 783.75  2.299E+002
 784.00  2.302E+002
 784.25  2.307E+002
 784.50  2.321E+002
 784.75  2.325E+002
 785.00  2.310E+002
 785.25  2.283E+002
 785.50  2.265E+002
 785.75  2.260E+002
 786.00  2.260E+002
 786.25  2.264E+002
 786.50  2.282E+002
 786.75  2.290E+002
 787.00  2.293E+002
 787.25  2.281E+002
 787.50  2.272E+002
 787.75  2.269E+002
 788.00  2.269E+002
 788.25  2.268E+002
 788.50  2.270E+002
 788.75  2.294E+002
 789.00  2.294E+002
 789.25  2.278E+002
 789.50  2.277E+002
 789.75  2.298E+002
 790.00  2.301E+002
 790.25  2.294E+002
 790.50  2.284E+002
 790.75  2.284E+002
 791.00  2.292E+002
 791.25  2.290E+002
 791.50  2.289E+002
 791.75  2.293E+002
 792.00  2.287E+002
 792.25  2.271E+002
 792.50  2.264E+002
 792.75  2.286E+002
 793.00  2.307E+002
 793.25  2.331E+002
 793.50  2.373E+002
 793.75  2.492E+002
 794.00  2.921E+002
 794.25  4.051E+002
 794.50  6.022E+002
 794.75  8.575E+002
 795.00  1.146E+003
 795.25  1.381E+003
 795.50  1.544E+003
 795.75  1.669E+003
 796.00  1.766E+003
 796.25  1.794E+003
 796.50  1.776E+003
 796.75  1.787E+003
 797.00  1.799E+003
 797.25  1.738E+003
 797.50  1.567E+003
 797.75  1.332E+003
 798.00  1.082E+003
 798.25  8.442E+002
 798.50  6.361E+002
 798.75  4.800E+002
 799.00  3.793E+002
 799.25  3.207E+002
 799.50  2.876E+002
 799.75  2.687E+002
 800.00  2.587E+002
 800.25  2.547E+002
 800.50  2.544E+002
 800.75  2.558E+002
 801.00  2.602E+002
 801.25  2.697E+002
 801.50  2.843E+002
 801.75  3.153E+002
 802.00  3.781E+002
 802.25  4.739E+002
 802.50  6.019E+002
 802.75  7.539E+002
 803.00  9.047E+002
 803.25  1.027E+003
 803.50  1.087E+003
 803.75  1.075E+003
 804.00  1.023E+003
 804.25  9.580E+002
 804.50  8.759E+002
 804.75  7.884E+002
 805.00  6.993E+002
 805.25  6.010E+002
 805.50  5.116E+002
 805.75  4.385E+002
 806.00  3.765E+002
 806.25  3.250E+002
 806.50  2.895E+002
 806.75  2.666E+002
 807.00  2.500E+002
 807.25  2.398E+002
 807.50  2.367E+002
 807.75  2.359E+002
 808.00  2.349E+002
 808.25  2.332E+002
 808.50  2.306E+002
 808.75  2.284E+002
 809.00  2.277E+002
 809.25  2.288E+002
 809.50  2.279E+002
 809.75  2.283E+002
 810.00  2.288E+002
 810.25  2.305E+002
 810.50  2.314E+002
 810.75  2.305E+002
 811.00  2.310E+002
 811.25  2.324E+002
 811.50  2.314E+002
 811.75  2.291E+002
 812.00  2.279E+002
 812.25  2.286E+002
 812.50  2.288E+002
 812.75  2.278E+002
 813.00  2.264E+002
 813.25  2.261E+002
 813.50  2.268E+002
 813.75  2.271E+002
 814.00  2.264E+002
 814.25  2.264E+002
 814.50  2.258E+002
 814.75  2.260E+002
 815.00  2.270E+002
 815.25  2.285E+002
 815.50  2.275E+002
 815.75  2.284E+002
 816.00  2.278E+002
 816.25  2.275E+002
 816.50  2.268E+002
 816.75  2.253E+002
 817.00  2.233E+002
 817.25  2.235E+002
 817.50  2.251E+002
 817.75  2.257E+002
 818.00  2.251E+002
 818.25  2.262E+002
 818.50  2.285E+002
 818.75  2.284E+002
 819.00  2.258E+002
 819.25  2.229E+002
 819.50  2.241E+002
 819.75  2.261E+002
 820.00  2.260E+002
 820.25  2.257E+002
 820.50  2.251E+002
 820.75  2.233E+002
 821.00  2.220E+002
 821.25  2.234E+002
 821.50  2.255E+002
 821.75  2.268E+002
 822.00  2.280E+002
 822.25  2.274E+002
 822.50  2.249E+002
 822.75  2.242E+002
 823.00  2.249E+002
 823.25  2.247E+002
 823.50  2.250E+002
 823.75  2.252E+002
 824.00  2.232E+002
 824.25  2.220E+002
 824.50  2.230E+002
 824.75  2.243E+002
 825.00  2.262E+002
 825.25  2.280E+002
 825.50  2.274E+002
 825.75  2.242E+002
 826.00  2.212E+002
 826.25  2.196E+002
 826.50  2.205E+002
 826.75  2.201E+002
 827.00  2.193E+002
 827.25  2.204E+002
 827.50  2.227E+002
 827.75  2.235E+002
 828.00  2.226E+002
 828.25  2.222E+002
 828.50  2.229E+002
 828.75  2.251E+002
 829.00  2.252E+002
 829.25  2.248E+002
 829.50  2.231E+002
 829.75  2.228E+002
 830.00  2.228E+002
 830.25  2.238E+002
 830.50  2.256E+002
 830.75  2.249E+002
 831.00  2.235E+002
 831.25  2.227E+002
 831.50  2.229E+002
 831.75  2.220E+002
 832.00  2.221E+002
 832.25  2.210E+002
 832.50  2.221E+002
 832.75  2.267E+002
 833.00  2.289E+002
 833.25  2.266E+002
 833.50  2.249E+002
 833.75  2.236E+002
 834.00  2.231E+002
 834.25  2.219E+002
 834.50  2.199E+002
 834.75  2.201E+002
 835.00  2.213E+002
 835.25  2.228E+002
 835.50  2.251E+002
 835.75  2.277E+002
 836.00  2.285E+002
 836.25  2.262E+002
 836.50  2.221E+002
 836.75  2.199E+002
 837.00  2.190E+002
 837.25  2.189E+002
 837.50  2.193E+002
 837.75  2.195E+002
 838.00  2.189E+002
 838.25  2.200E+002
 838.50  2.221E+002
 838.75  2.230E+002
 839.00  2.250E+002
 839.25  2.266E+002
 839.50  2.272E+002
 839.75  2.254E+002
 840.00  2.243E+002
 840.25  2.248E+002
 840.50  2.240E+002
 840.75  2.214E+002
 841.00  2.195E+002
 841.25  2.189E+002
 841.50  2.196E+002
 841.75  2.207E+002
 842.00  2.215E+002
 842.25  2.224E+002
 842.50  2.230E+002
 842.75  2.238E+002
 843.00  2.236E+002
 843.25  2.217E+002
 843.50  2.204E+002
 843.75  2.210E+002
 844.00  2.215E+002
 844.25  2.204E+002
 844.50  2.188E+002
 844.75  2.177E+002
 845.00  2.194E+002
 845.25  2.213E+002
 845.50  2.222E+002
 845.75  2.210E+002
 846.00  2.193E+002
 846.25  2.196E+002
 846.50  2.206E+002
 846.75  2.205E+002
 847.00  2.207E+002
 847.25  2.217E+002
 847.50  2.223E+002
 847.75  2.240E+002
 848.00  2.251E+002
 848.25  2.239E+002
 848.50  2.191E+002
 848.75  2.164E+002
 849.00  2.161E+002
 849.25  2.167E+002
 849.50  2.178E+002
 849.75  2.204E+002
 850.00  2.227E+002
 850.25  2.239E+002
 850.50  2.239E+002
 850.75  2.225E+002
 851.00  2.217E+002
 851.25  2.207E+002
 851.50  2.209E+002
 851.75  2.205E+002
 852.00  2.197E+002
 852.25  2.176E+002
 852.50  2.160E+002
 852.75  2.167E+002
 853.00  2.188E+002
 853.25  2.184E+002
 853.50  2.204E+002
 853.75  2.224E+002
 854.00  2.232E+002
 854.25  2.238E+002
 854.50  2.250E+002
 854.75  2.237E+002
 855.00  2.192E+002
 855.25  2.161E+002
 855.50  2.145E+002
 855.75  2.142E+002
 856.00  2.169E+002
 856.25  2.196E+002
 856.50  2.211E+002
 856.75  2.220E+002
 857.00  2.216E+002
 857.25  2.222E+002
 857.50  2.224E+002
 857.75  2.225E+002
 858.00  2.221E+002
 858.25  2.221E+002
 858.50  2.201E+002
 858.75  2.176E+002
 859.00  2.183E+002
 859.25  2.205E+002
 859.50  2.214E+002
 859.75  2.214E+002
 860.00  2.214E+002
 860.25  2.197E+002
 860.50  2.182E+002
 860.75  2.168E+002
 861.00  2.156E+002
 861.25  2.163E+002
 861.50  2.184E+002
 861.75  2.202E+002
 862.00  2.211E+002
 862.25  2.198E+002
 862.50  2.197E+002
 862.75  2.212E+002
 863.00  2.223E+002
 863.25  2.198E+002
 863.50  2.192E+002
 863.75  2.162E+002
 864.00  2.162E+002
 864.25  2.176E+002
 864.50  2.195E+002
 864.75  2.208E+002
 865.00  2.200E+002
 865.25  2.180E+002
 865.50  2.165E+002
 865.75  2.164E+002
 866.00  2.158E+002
 866.25  2.154E+002
 866.50  2.172E+002
 866.75  2.205E+002
 867.00  2.230E+002
 867.25  2.224E+002
 867.50  2.234E+002
 867.75  2.235E+002
 868.00  2.238E+002
 868.25  2.227E+002
 868.50  2.221E+002
 868.75  2.211E+002
 869.00  2.191E+002
 869.25  2.170E+002
 869.50  2.173E+002
 869.75  2.181E+002
 870.00  2.193E+002
 870.25  2.189E+002
 870.50  2.184E+002
 870.75  2.181E+002
 871.00  2.182E+002
 871.25  2.191E+002
 871.50  2.200E+002
 871.75  2.196E+002
 872.00  2.170E+002
 872.25  2.143E+002
 872.50  2.123E+002
 872.75  2.120E+002
 873.00  2.128E+002
 873.25  2.131E+002
 873.50  2.151E+002
 873.75  2.178E+002
 874.00  2.209E+002
 874.25  2.230E+002
 874.50  2.213E+002
 874.75  2.187E+002
 875.00  2.165E+002
 875.25  2.169E+002
 875.50  2.181E+002
 875.75  2.187E+002
 876.00  2.178E+002
 876.25  2.172E+002
 876.50  2.164E+002
 876.75  2.156E+002
 877.00  2.148E+002
 877.25  2.152E+002
 877.50  2.175E+002
 877.75  2.167E+002
 878.00  2.165E+002
 878.25  2.186E+002
 878.50  2.220E+002
 878.75  2.218E+002
 879.00  2.190E+002
 879.25  2.170E+002
 879.50  2.173E+002
 879.75  2.190E+002
 880.00  2.205E+002
 880.25  2.225E+002
 880.50  2.216E+002
 880.75  2.194E+002
 881.00  2.179E+002
 881.25  2.161E+002
 881.50  2.148E+002
 881.75  2.145E+002
 882.00  2.158E+002
 882.25  2.173E+002
 882.50  2.177E+002
 882.75  2.180E+002
 883.00  2.196E+002
 883.25  2.198E+002
 883.50  2.175E+002
 883.75  2.172E+002
 884.00  2.170E+002
 884.25  2.156E+002
 884.50  2.147E+002
 884.75  2.146E+002
 885.00  2.169E+002
 885.25  2.177E+002
 885.50  2.174E+002
 885.75  2.176E+002
 886.00  2.182E+002
 886.25  2.188E+002
 886.50  2.206E+002
 886.75  2.198E+002
 887.00  2.172E+002
 887.25  2.158E+002
 887.50  2.159E+002
 887.75  2.161E+002
 888.00  2.153E+002
 888.25  2.153E+002
 888.50  2.166E+002
 888.75  2.170E+002
 889.00  2.155E+002
 889.25  2.162E+002
 889.50  2.185E+002
 889.75  2.186E+002
 890.00  2.171E+002
 890.25  2.161E+002
 890.50  2.158E+002
 890.75  2.170E+002
 891.00  2.172E+002
 891.25  2.158E+002
 891.50  2.138E+002
 891.75  2.134E+002
 892.00  2.149E+002
 892.25  2.166E+002
 892.50  2.189E+002
 892.75  2.205E+002
 893.00  2.196E+002
 893.25  2.185E+002
 893.50  2.177E+002
 893.75  2.160E+002
 894.00  2.137E+002
 894.25  2.128E+002
 894.50  2.142E+002
 894.75  2.166E+002
 895.00  2.185E+002
 895.25  2.196E+002
 895.50  2.198E+002
 895.75  2.180E+002
 896.00  2.170E+002
 896.25  2.164E+002
 896.50  2.167E+002
 896.75  2.178E+002
 897.00  2.166E+002
 897.25  2.142E+002
 897.50  2.139E+002
 897.75  2.139E+002
 898.00  2.142E+002
 898.25  2.144E+002
 898.50  2.134E+002
 898.75  2.117E+002
 899.00  2.129E+002
 899.25  2.136E+002
 899.50  2.142E+002
 899.75  2.156E+002
 900.00  2.161E+002
 900.25  2.152E+002
 900.50  2.140E+002
 900.75  2.124E+002
 901.00  2.125E+002
 901.25  2.141E+002
 901.50  2.158E+002
 901.75  2.164E+002
 902.00  2.164E+002
 902.25  2.156E+002
 902.50  2.119E+002
 902.75  2.093E+002
 903.00  2.116E+002
 903.25  2.140E+002
 903.50  2.154E+002
 903.75  2.169E+002
 904.00  2.169E+002
 904.25  2.165E+002
 904.50  2.165E+002
 904.75  2.175E+002
 905.00  2.173E+002
 905.25  2.146E+002
 905.50  2.132E+002
 905.75  2.148E+002
 906.00  2.167E+002
 906.25  2.162E+002
 906.50  2.161E+002
 906.75  2.158E+002
 907.00  2.139E+002
 907.25  2.118E+002
 907.50  2.117E+002
 907.75  2.128E+002
 908.00  2.144E+002
 908.25  2.147E+002
 908.50  2.140E+002
 908.75  2.132E+002
 909.00  2.129E+002
 909.25  2.135E+002
 909.50  2.140E+002
 909.75  2.139E+002
 910.00  2.135E+002
 910.25  2.146E+002
 910.50  2.152E+002
 910.75  2.148E+002
 911.00  2.150E+002
 911.25  2.159E+002
 911.50  2.162E+002
 911.75  2.154E+002
 912.00  2.137E+002
 912.25  2.134E+002
 912.50  2.136E+002
 912.75  2.141E+002
 913.00  2.130E+002
 913.25  2.118E+002
 913.50  2.150E+002
 913.75  2.200E+002
 914.00  2.211E+002
 914.25  2.196E+002
 914.50  2.176E+002
 914.75  2.132E+002
 915.00  2.100E+002
 915.25  2.098E+002
 915.50  2.098E+002
 915.75  2.105E+002
 916.00  2.118E+002
 916.25  2.116E+002
 916.50  2.124E+002
 916.75  2.140E+002
 917.00  2.157E+002
 917.25  2.159E+002
 917.50  2.155E+002
 917.75  2.146E+002
 918.00  2.146E+002
 918.25  2.174E+002
 918.50  2.187E+002
 918.75  2.163E+002
 919.00  2.155E+002
 919.25  2.141E+002
 919.50  2.122E+002
 919.75  2.122E+002
 920.00  2.134E+002
 920.25  2.163E+002
 920.50  2.185E+002
 920.75  2.205E+002
 921.00  2.205E+002
 921.25  2.190E+002
 921.50  2.160E+002
 921.75  2.148E+002
 922.00  2.149E+002
 922.25  2.144E+002
 922.50  2.151E+002
 922.75  2.144E+002
 923.00  2.134E+002
 923.25  2.146E+002
 923.50  2.177E+002
 923.75  2.195E+002
 924.00  2.178E+002
 924.25  2.167E+002
 924.50  2.171E+002
 924.75  2.174E+002
 925.00  2.165E+002
 925.25  2.158E+002
 925.50  2.143E+002
 925.75  2.139E+002
 926.00  2.165E+002
 926.25  2.175E+002
 926.50  2.164E+002
 926.75  2.156E+002
 927.00  2.161E+002
 927.25  2.169E+002
 927.50  2.159E+002
 927.75  2.163E+002
 928.00  2.176E+002
 928.25  2.165E+002
 928.50  2.133E+002
 928.75  2.111E+002
 929.00  2.118E+002
 929.25  2.124E+002
 929.50  1.961E+002
 929.75  4.606E+001
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You included useless code like font information, but we don't know the structure of your data.